# RequireJS local var not matching

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Can anyone explain why this might be the case?

I am in a RequireJS module that has zero dependencies. I am trying to create a singleton that represents the view state, to avoid a global variable. But for some reason the getter that is trying to retrieve a property from the view var is not matching. Is there any way to explain what is going on in the image?

view is defined, and the viewName value is defined, but it's somehow not picking up view.mainView.

[image]

Comment: you might need to zoom in to see the picture

Comment: In general, you'd get much better answers pasting in your code than pasting in a picture of your code.

Comment: seeing is believing, the IDE shows the truth

Comment: Yes, but this truth is very small and hard on the eyes :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to check if `view[viewName]` is defined on `view`, but you're actually checking to see if `view[viewName]` has a truth-y value.

Try this:

```
if(viewName in view) {
    view[viewName] = $view;
} else {
    throw new Error('no view matched');
}
```

Comment: Yes, looks like you have to go through `set` to set the view, so on the first call you'll always be checking `if (view[viewName])`, which will always evaluate to `if (null)`.